# How to show author page link

Tags: author, links

I have the following code:

```
/*Get number of entries*/
    function get_entries_num( $id ) {
        $count=  count_user_posts( $id );
        if ($count == 1) 
        {
            return sprintf(__('%s total post','upme'), $post, $count);
        } else 
        {
            return sprintf(__('%s total posts','upme'), $count);
        }
    }
```

I want to link "%s total posts" this location `get_author_posts_url($author_id)`.

So, I want to display WordPress user all post(author page) when someone click on "%s total posts".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
/*Get number of entries*/
function get_entries_num( $id ) {
    $count=  count_user_posts( $id );
    if ($count == 1) 
    {
        return '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url($id).'">'.sprintf(__('%s total post','upme'), $count).'</a>';
    } else 
    {
        return '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url($id).'">'.sprintf(__('%s total posts','upme'), $count).'</a>';
    }
}
```